# Riak Security in Cluster

Tags: riak

I am finding difficulty while setting up Riak Kv Cluster setup using java client.

Can anybody tell how we do that??

Achually i tried with below code to use riak security in cluster but i am getting error of SSLEngine Problem, can anybody tell how we resolve this issues.

**Below is java Code for Refference**

```
InputStream inputStream = null;
        KeyStore ks = null;
        try {
            // inputStream = new FileInputStream("/ssl_dir/cacertfile.pem");

            inputStream = new FileInputStream("/home/shahzad/Desktop/amit/rootCA.pem");
            // Generate an X509Certificate from the InputStream
            CertificateFactory certFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
            X509Certificate caCert = (X509Certificate) certFactory.generateCertificate(inputStream);
            inputStream.close();
            // Generate a KeyStore object
            ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
            ks.load(null, "password".toCharArray());
            ks.setCertificateEntry("cacert", caCert);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



synchronized (RiakConfig.class) {
            List<RiakNode> riakNodeList = new ArrayList<RiakNode>();
            for (final String riakServer : riakServerArray) {
                RiakNode node = new RiakNode.Builder()
                        .withMinConnections(10)
                        .withMinConnections(50)
                        .withRemoteAddress(riakServer.split(":")[0])
                        .withRemotePort(
                                Integer.parseInt(riakServer.split(":")[1]))
                        .withAuth("shahzad", "shahzad", ks)
                        .build();
                riakNodeList.add(node);
            }
            // This cluster object takes our one node as an argument
            cluster = new RiakCluster.Builder(riakNodeList).build();
            // The cluster must be started to work, otherwise you will see
            // errors
            cluster.start();
        }
```

Tell one thing..... how we access security enable Riak KV remotely.

Answer (score 0):

Please check, if you enable security at Riak KV cluster and added client source

```
riak-admin security add-source all <<127.0.0.1/32>> trust
```

The IP address belongs to the client machine from where the connection will originate